# overridey Destroy but keep callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

ActiveRecod model which overrides the destroy method to actually just "soft-delete" the object. We do create many before_filters, dynamically but they won't be called, if we override the destroy method.

```
before_destroy {
  p "before_destroy"
}

def destroy
  soft_delete
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def destroy
    _run_destroy_callbacks do
      soft_delete
    end
  end
```